# Tensorflow Checkpoint Custom Map

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am subclassing a keras model with custom layers. Each layer wraps a dictionary of parameters that is used when generating they layers. It seems these param dictionaries are not set before the training checkpoint is made in Tensorflow, they are set after, which causes an error. I am not sure how to fix this, as the `ValueError` being raised also gives outdated information (`tf.contrib` no longer exists).

> ValueError: Unable to save the object {'units': 32, 'activation':
>   'tanh', 'recurrent_initializer': 'glorot_uniform', 'dropout': 0,
>   'return_sequences': True} (a dictionary wrapper constructed
>   automatically on attribute assignment). The wrapped dictionary was
>   modified outside the wrapper (its final value was {'units': 32,
>   'activation': 'tanh', 'recurrent_initializer': 'glorot_uniform',
>   'dropout': 0, 'return_sequences': True}, its value when a checkpoint
>   dependency was added was None), which breaks restoration on object
>   creation.
>
> If you don't need this dictionary checkpointed, wrap it in a
>   tf.contrib.checkpoint.NoDependency object; it will be automatically
>   un-wrapped and subsequently ignored.

Here's an example of the Layer that is throwing this issue:

```
class RecurrentConfig(BaseLayer):
    '''Basic configurable recurrent layer'''
    def __init__(self, params: Dict[Any, Any], mode: ModeKeys, layer_name: str = '', **kwargs):
        self.layer_name = layer_name
        self.cell_name = params.pop('cell', 'GRU')
        self.num_layers = params.pop('num_layers', 1)
        kwargs['name'] = layer_name
        super().__init__(params, mode, **kwargs)
        if layer_name == '':
            self.layer_name = self.cell_name
        self.layers: List[layers.Layer] = stack_layers(self.params,
                                                       self.num_layers,
                                                       self.cell_name)

    def call(self, inputs: np.ndarray) -> layers.Layer:
        '''This function is a sequential/functional call to this layers logic
        Args:
            inputs: Array to be processed within this layer
        Returns:
            inputs processed through this layer'''
        processed = inputs
        for layer in self.layers:
            processed = layer(processed)
        return processed

    @staticmethod
    def default_params() -> Dict[Any, Any]:
        return{
            'units': 32,
            'recurrent_initializer': 'glorot_uniform',
            'dropout': 0,
            'recurrent_dropout': 0,
            'activation': 'tanh',
            'return_sequences': True
        }
```

BaseLayer.py

```
'''Basic ABC for a keras style layer'''

from typing import Dict, Any

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from mosaix_py.mosaix_learn.configurable import Configurable

class BaseLayer(Configurable, layers.Layer):
    '''Base configurable Keras layer'''
    def get_config(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        '''Return configuration dictionary as part of keras serialization'''
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update(self.params)
        return config

    @staticmethod
    def default_params() -> Dict[Any, Any]:
        raise NotImplementedError('Layer does not implement default params')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue I was facing was that I was popping items form a dictionary passed into a layers.Layer

```
    self.cell_name = params.pop('cell', 'GRU')
    self.num_layers = params.pop('num_layers', 1)
```

When passing a dictionary into a layer it must remain unchanged as it is tracked.

My solution was to further abstract away parameter parsing and pass in a finalized dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much. This last sentence ("abstracting away...") is key in solving the issue. In my case, I had `dict`s that look like `{0: val_0, 1: val_1, 2: val_2, ...}` saved as model attributes ('`self`'). Since the keys (0, 1, 2, ...) are easily reproducible, I then stored only the values (v0, v1, v2, ...) in a `tuple` as attributes instead. This allowed me to use `dict(enumerate(self.values))` to recreate the original `dict`s as local variables where needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `RecurrentConfig` object should inherit from [`tf.keras.layers.Layer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) instead of `BaseLayer`. The TF documentation on [checkpoints/delayed restorations](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#delayed_restorations) covers why:

> `Layer` objects in TensorFlow may delay the creation of variables to their first call, when input shapes are available. For example the shape of a Dense layer's kernel depends on both the layer's input and output shapes, and so the output shape required as a constructor argument is not enough information to create the variable on its own. Since calling a Layer also reads the variable's value, a restore must happen between the variable's creation and its first use.
>
> To support this idiom, `tf.train.Checkpoint` queues restores which don't yet have a matching variable.

Comment: BaseLayer itself inherits from tf.keras.layers.Layer so this should not be an issue, I will add that code.